# CSV Export failure from SQL View - line breaks after export

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv, export-to-csv

I have a SQL view which contains a column with concatenated text.

This text comes from a function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FC01_FunctionName]
    (@OrderNr VARCHAR(200)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
BEGIN
    declare @r varchar(2000)
    declare @z varchar(2000)

    DECLARE cc CURSOR FOR
        SELECT SL.Description 
        FROM dbo.[DBName] SL
        WHERE x = @OrderNr AND y = 1

    SET @r = ''

    OPEN cc

    WHILE ( 0 = 0 ) 
    BEGIN
        fetch next from cc into @z

        if (@@fetch_status <> 0) 
            break

        if ( @r = '' ) 
        begin
            set @r = @z
        end
        else
        begin
            set @r = @r + char(13) + char(10) + @z 
        end
    end

    close cc
    deallocate cc

    return @r
end
```

The result looks like:

[image]

As you can see sometimes it's just 'one' text-element like 'Call 24 hrs. ...' and sometimes there are multiple text elements like '*** Item No ...**   **Please ...*** ...' and so on.

Every time I export the view to a `.csv` file, I got problems with rows which have more than one text element. It results in a new line for every additional text element and destroys the format (all the yellow marked text should be in one field -> the field with the text '***Item ...'):

[image]

After the last (yellow marked) text-element the normal entries go on.

The properties of the job which does the SQL view to `.csv` export are the following:

```
sqlcmd -W -s ";"  -E  -d master -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT *  FROM [DB].[dbo].[ViewName];" -o "c:\Temp\XXX.csv"
```

I believe that the export function thinks that the text-elements are separate and thats maybe the reason why the functions decides to spend a new line for every element. 
I also believe that I have to change something in the sql function which creates the result for the field or maybe in the view itsself which gets the data.

This is the part of the sql query in the view which gets the data:

```
(SELECT [dbo].[FC01_FunctionName] (  x.[FieldName]) ) as [ColumnName],
```

Any ideas? Thanks for you help!

Comment: You are inserting `char(13) + char(10)` which is line break for any text reader.

Comment: Perfect! Thats it! I removed the char(13) and replaced the char(10) with ' ' to have a space character. So easy, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your text to columns settings in Excel. It may be that the csv export is correct (open in notepad to check) but Excel splits the lines as the file is opened.

Comment: do you know where I find them?

Comment: Data/Text to Columns. Whatever you use is stored for the next use, including opening files.